# Selenium script works manually but not on startup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pi

I have a selenium script running on a pi model 3B+, the script works just fine when run manually using /usr/bin/python /home/pi/main.py but when running it using crontab or LXDE-pi/autostart it just starts up the browser and doesn't continue doing what it should do. I tried to log information using the logging library but see nothing useful. At first I thought it was because selenium wasn't installed with sudo but it works when python is launched with sudo as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import logging

logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG)
#Set chromedriver to kiosk mode and disable
#info popup of "Chrome is being run by test software"
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chromeOptions.add_argument("--kiosk")
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
#Disable the save password popup
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
})

#Initiate chrome driver with set options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
#Set implicit wait time to make sure everything is loaded, default is 0
driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
#Navigate to URL
driver.get(url)
#Name of mail form on login page
mail_name = "loginfmt"
#Wait until element is present and interactable
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, mail_name)))

mail_form = driver.find_element_by_name(mail_name)
#Fill out the email and hit enter
mail_form.send_keys(usr)
mail_form.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#Name of password form on login page
pass_name = "passwd"
#Wait until element is present and interactable
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, pass_name)))
pass_form = driver.find_element_by_name(pass_name)
#Fill out the password and hit enter
pass_form.send_keys(passwd)
pass_form.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Here is the output from the logging file

```
DEBUG:root:Adding chrome options
DEBUG:root:Disabling the save password popup
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:38727/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:38727 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 423
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:root:Adding chrome options
DEBUG:root:Disabling the save password popup
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:35557/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:35557 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 423
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:root:Adding chrome options
DEBUG:root:Disabling the save password popup
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:34903/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:34903 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 423
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:root:Adding chrome options
DEBUG:root:Disabling the save password popup
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:40785/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "any"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions": {"excludeSwitches": ["enable-automation"], "prefs": {"profile": {"password_manager_enabled": false}, "credentials_enable_service": false}, "extensions": [], "useAutomationExtension": false, "args": ["--kiosk"]}, "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:40785 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 423
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
```

What I added to "crontab -e -u pi":

```
@reboot python /home/pi/main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I couldn't use SSH to start the script and have it appear on the screen which led me to the idea that helped me find the solution here
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101126/how-to-schedule-in-crontab-a-python-script-with-selenium-driver-to-show-chromiu

Turns out you basically just need to specify which screen it needs to display it on! Hope it helps someone, it took me hours to find this solution which is so simple!!!!

```
crontab -e 
@reboot env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY" /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/test.py
```